# Sending $data Variable From Model To View

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Okay, so I have this snippet of code in a controller. However, it's all DB driven and should really be in model - I get that. However, as you can see in the IF statement, I need to pass along $data to my view. Based on the outcome. I tried pasting this chuck of coding in a method in my model (calling the model method via controller), however the $data[update_prompt] string is not getting called by the view...

How would I translate this code into a model - sending the $data values back to my controller to embed in my view?

```
    // show appropriate upgrade message if user has free account

    $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id'); 

    $this->db->select('subscription'); // select the subscription column
    $this->db->where('id', $id); //find id in table that matches session id
    $query = $this->db->get("subscriptions"); // connect to this database
    $subscribe = $query->result_array(); //returns the result of the above

    if($subscribe[0]['subscription'] == 'freebie') // if subscription column equals 'freebie' in the $subscribe array, do this:
    {
        $data['update_prompt'] = $this -> load -> view('shared/upgrade_subscription', '', TRUE); // adds view within view, $update_prompt
    }
    else 
    {
        $data['update_prompt'] = '';
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would add a function in your model, like so:

```
public function myModelFunction($id) {

    //we return row as we are looking up by primary key and are guaranteed only one row
    return $this->db->select('subscription')
                    ->where('id', $id)
                    ->get('subscriptions')
                    ->row();
}
```

Then, in your controller:

```
public function myControllerFunction() {

    $subscribe = $this->my_model->myModelFunction($this->session->userdata('id'));
    if($subscribe->subscription == 'freebie') // if subscription column equals 'freebie' in the $subscribe array, do this:
    {
        $data['update_prompt'] = $this -> load -> view('shared/upgrade_subscription', '', TRUE); // adds view within view, $update_prompt
    }
    else 
    {
        $data['update_prompt'] = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: that looks like it should do the trick. Question though while I go test - why put the session data there? And not within the model method?

Comment: Hi Mike, you would put the session data in your function call as opposed to the function definition as you want your model to be flexible - what if you want to return a subscript ID that is not equal to the current session ID?  Then you'd have to write a whole other model function to do this for you

Comment: Agh! Okay, makes a lot of sense. Sorry, newbie here! :) Thanks for your help! Works!!

Comment: Great, no problem!  Good luck with CI and if you need any more help, feel free to ask me.